# Prevent HTML input from moving when overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have to HTML elements on screen: an input textfield, and a container which hides the overflow of an input textfield.

I need to maintain the space to the left of the textfield.
[image: I need to keep the red left of the textfield]

However, when the text reaches the far right of what's visible of the textfield, the textfield shifts left to reveal what you're typing.

[image: The red to the left is gone now]

***How can I prevent this behavior? Here is a jsfiddle of my issue.***
https://jsfiddle.net/531m67jw/

Here's my code...

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="textfield" type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}

#textfield {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **It's actually not taking up the space on the left. The browser is just ensuring that you can see where you are typing.** When you add `overflow:hidden`, it hides the scroll which makes it confusing to understand. 

You'll see the correct behavior when you replace `overflow:hidden` by `overflow:auto`.

Comment: @thebrownkid Are you sure? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Take a look at this jsfiddle. When the text exits the container, the entire input shifts left. https://jsfiddle.net/btov3e6n/

Comment: Yes, it looks like the textbox moved towards the left but actually it has a hidden scroll which moved. Make the CSS change as I mentioned in my above comment and you'll see  the behavior.

Comment: @thebrownkid Ahh, I see. Thank you! I'd still like scrolling disabled though. Whatever is outside of the container needs to be invisible. Is this possible?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use of having a textbox hidden partially? Btw related to your question, it is very unlikely to get a decent fix on what you are trying to achieve as it's the normal behavior of browsers and textboxes to keep focus on the part you are typing.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I'm building a canvas application that's 800px x 600px, and I'm placing input elements over it, but I don't want the textboxes visible outside of the boundaries of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run this code in Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
setInterval(function(){
container.scrollLeft = "0px";
}, 100);
```

Put less milliseconds if you want it to be faster.

Also if you can detect that it is changing its position, I'm pretty sure there is a way to call a function before every frame in Javascript, so you could try to do that.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! I was hoping for a HTML/CSS-only solution, but this hack will do the trick.